# Security of private key when using "insecure" OpenSSL methods

Tags: ruby, cryptography, openssl, rsa

I recently came across a situation where I *absolutely* needed to use the method `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA#params`. However, the doc says the following:

> THIS METHOD IS INSECURE, PRIVATE INFORMATION CAN LEAK OUT!!!
>
> ...
>
> Don’t use :-)) (It’s up to you)

What does this mean? How is the private key normally protected within the instance of the RSA key and how is this different from any regular object?

Can I prevent information from leaking by doing something like this, where the method is only accessed within a lambda:

```
private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate(2048)

save_private = lambda do
  key = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA512.new.digest("password")
  aes = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("AES-256-CFB")
  iv = OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(aes.iv_len)
  aes.encrypt
  aes.key, aes.iv = key, iv
  aes.update(private_key.params.to_s) + aes.final
end

private_enc, save_private = save_private.call, nil
```

Also, if this security problem has anything to do with variables lingering in memory awaiting GC, can forcing garbage collection make things more secure?

```
GC.start
```

Thanks in advance to anybody who can clear this up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to give away information of the private key. The key components need to be available to perform any signing operation or decryption so normally the key information is in memory in the clear. Obviously if you retrieve it you must make sure that you keep it safe. I presume that this is where the warning comes in.

You can do all kinds of things like encrypting the private key parameters, but then you get to a point where you have to store the decryption key. Basically this will end up being impossible to solve without an external system (or a person keeping a password).

Comment: Was anything missing from my answer, louism?